# How do you display a PNG image in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

How do you display a PNG image in WP7 starting in coordinate (X,Y), and using XNA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the image to the XNA content project (drag drop the file).

In the game class add a variable that holds the texture reference:

```
Texture2D tex;
```

In the LoadContent() method load the texture:

```
tex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("texturename");
```

texturename has to be the texture's asset name. By default this is the filename without extension.

In the Draw() method draw the texture at a given position x, y:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(tex, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

This is one of the most basic tasks in XNA. Before asking somebody, you should try to find the solution on your own. It would have taken about half a minute to find the answer on the internet.